# Shortcut for Confluence macro settings

Tags: confluence

When editing a confluence page you can use the open curly brace to get a shortcut menu for the macros.
For exampl `{Code` will select the code macro.

If you insert the code macro and double click on it, you can set the language, and title etc.

Is there a shortcut to set these properties? Something like typing the following:

```
{Code Block | Language = sql | title = Some code example
```

This is sort of how it looks when its manually configured anyway:

[image]

Comment: And the big question is ...?

Comment: Just to clarify, by "shortcut", you're referring to accomplishing the process by initially specifying the desired parameters directly, as part of the edit, rather than going through a multi-step dialog?

Comment: Yes, that's right fixer1234